# inline-block div elements not vertically aligned when content is added

Tags: html, css

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Team.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.14.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet"> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/textition.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SparkHome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="Event.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <div class="mainWrapper">
        <div class="main">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand ml-0">
      <h1 style="
      font-size:40px;
      color: white;
      " class="d-lg-none"> Logo</h1>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav pt-2 pb-2">
          <li class="nav-item mt-0" id="navItems">
            <a href="SparkHome.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mt-0" id="navItemsActive">
            <a href="#">The Team</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mt-0" id="navItems">
            The Event
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mt-0" id="navItems">
            <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1WpEQ4nF4y-mGUiz2hv1gEH-D58_j0pEWGttdfEhsdqQ/viewform?edit_requested=true" target="-_blank">Volunteer</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mt-0" id="navItems">
            <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScC9lS7uMstAmGXrQ41g0uEe3qXmmHHmipvOd1Rzae6LEEB2Q/viewform"target="_blank">Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  <h1 class="heading">The Event</h1>
  <hr class="headingHR">


  <div class="block">
    <h1 class="eventTitle">
      Cubing
    </h1>
    <p class="eventContent">
      The real reason behind the creation of this organisation. We founder members are passionate cubers, in need of a platform to learn and show our skills. This thirst created our organisation.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
     <h1 class="eventTitle">
    Surprise
  </h1>
  <p class="eventContent">Do you think that we'll tell you right now? Be there to witness the excitement.<br>EXPECT THE UNEXPECTED </p>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
     <h1 class="eventTitle">
    Logic Solving
  </h1><p class="eventContent">
    This event consists of 2 rounds. The first is a paper-based round that tests your logic and decision-making skills. The second is an actual, physical puzzle.
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="block">
     <h1 class="eventTitle">
    Horcrux Hunt
  </h1>
  <p class="eventContent"> In its first ever appearance at SPARK, participate in The Horcrux Hunt, scavenging for treasure items stowed away in the campus grounds.
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
     <h1 class="eventTitle">
    Fortnite
  </h1>
  <p class="eventContent">
    With a staggering 125 million active players, Fortnite is THE hottest game on the market right now.
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
     <h1 class="eventTitle">
    MCU event
  </h1>

  </div>
</div>


  </body>
  </html>
```

[This is how my page looks like when I add some content in the divs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3e6b.png%60)

```
.block {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height:300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:2px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  border-radius:20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.main {
  text-align: center!important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
.eventTitle {
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
font-size: 25px;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
.eventContent {
  color: white;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

When there is no content in the `.block` class, the divs are arranged and spaced evenly. However, as I add content (`.eventContent` class), the divs (`.block`) go haywire. They are set as `display:inline-block`. How might I go about getting the divs with content to be evenly spaced and arranged?

Comment: do you mind to share the html too? you can create a snippet with <> instead of just pasting code

Comment: @LelioFaieta done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the margins, it is the vertical alignment of the `<div>` elements.

You should add this to your styles:

```
.block { vertical-align: top }
```

Depending on exactly how you want the vertical placement to work, you might change that to `vertical-align: text-top`. See the [CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) specs for details.
(NOTE the default is `vertical-align: baseline`, which aligns the bottom of the last line of text in each box to its neighbors).

Answer (score 0):

The elements which have class `.block` have `display: inline-block` applied to them. The default vertical alignment for inline-blocks is `baseline` (i.e the last text lines in the blocks are aligned)

So just add `vertical-align: top` to the CSS for the `.block` class to force their contents to the top and align them as desired.